# Linker not recognizing extern statement

Tags: c, gcc, ld, extern

I'm following the kernel development tutorial at [osdever](http://www.osdever.net/bkerndev/), and I'm at the printing to the screen portion of the tutorial. It compiles just fine, no errors or warnings, but when it goes to link, I get:

```
screen.o: In function `scroll':
screen.c:(.text+0x12c): undefined reference to `memcpy'
screen.o: In function `put_str':
screen.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `strlen'
```

I do have a include statement to system.h at the top of screen.c, and in system.h I have

```
#ifndef __SYSTEM_H
#define __SYSTEM_H

extern unsigned char *memcpy(unsigned char *dest, const unsigned char *src, int count);
extern unsigned char *memset(unsigned char *dest, unsigned char val, int count);
extern unsigned short *memsetw(unsigned short *dest, unsigned short val, int count);
extern int strlen(const char *str);
extern unsigned char inportb (unsigned short _port);
extern void outportb (unsigned short _port, unsigned char _data);
extern void clear();
extern void put_char(unsigned char c);
extern void put_str(unsigned char *str);
extern void set_color(unsigned char fcol, unsigned char bcol);
extern void init_video();

#endif
```

I can't find anything about this on the web, and there's no help in the tutorial. It seems that when I change the order in the linker statement, from

```
/usr/local/cross/bin/i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o main.o screen.o
```

to

```
/usr/local/cross/bin/i586-elf-ld -T link.ld -o kernel.bin start.o screen.o main.o
```

I get

```
screen.o: In function `put_str':
screen.c:(.text+0x249): undefined reference to `strlen'
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x9b): undefined reference to `init_video'
```

**Edit**
http://pastebin.com/ibBAVpe5 - Main.c

Comment: If you have `nm`, try it on the `.o` files.

Comment: @lhf I did, don't know what it means, but here it is:http://pastebin.com/mMEVf2bv

Comment: From the `nm` output you gave, there should not be any undefined references. BTW, `T` marks definitions and `U` marks uses. Every `U`in your output is matched by a `T`. So my guess is that you should try putting `main.o` first in the list of objects, though that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @lhf @geekosaur Thanks for the help. I guess I'll try recompiling gcc with a different target to see if that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided a `strlen`, so where exactly should it come from?  In a normal compile, the `ld` command line will have an `-lc` added to it by `cc` to bring in the standard library.  Given the indications that this is intended to be standalone, you will need to provide your own support routines such as `strlen` and `memcpy`; you can't use a standard C library (or would have to be very careful about it) because that will try to call into the kernel for some things.

## #

That doesn't explain the other problem with reordering objects, nor the discussion in the comments below.  This leads me to believe you have a broken or possibly incompatible linker script (the `-T link.ld`).  Paste that?

Comment: Which source file are they in?  The `extern` lines don't count; they're promises that you *do* have an actual definition somewhere.

Comment: Hrm. I don't see anything wrong with that (assuming it's the format introduced by the System V ELF linker and adopted by GNU). Now I wonder about the symbol tables, or maybe odder problems such as some things compiled natively and others cross-compiled. But that's getting a little difficult to debug here....